# How to initialize array of integer kind 8 in fortran?

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, fortran77, fortran95

I want to initialize an array of large integers in fortran, I have tried:

```
integer(kind=8) :: XGrid(1:20)
```

But the integers remain the default kind=4. As I later add numbers to the array:

```
XGrid = (/3002, 3340403,....,19460630000/)
```

And I receive a "This numeric constant is out of range" error. As it wont fit in a kind=4 int, but will in a kind=8 int.

I have also tried declaring it as:

```
integer, parameter :: ik8 = selected_int_kind(8) 
integer(ik8) :: XGrid(1:20)
```

But this also did not work.

Edit:
Thanks Vladimir F, but I am trying to define an array rather than just a single variable and as such I cant understand how to adapt the answer used in:
[Is There a Better Double-Precision Assignment in Fortran 90?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146005/is-there-a-better-double-precision-assignment-in-fortran-90)
Would it be:

```
integer, parameter :: ik8 = selected_int_kind(8) 
integer(ik8) :: XGrid(1:20)_ik8
XGrid = (/3002_ik8, 3340403_ik8,....,19460630000_ik8/)
```

or is it different? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, `kind=8` can be anything, it does not have to be 64-bit. Much better to use `int64` from `iso_fortran_env` instead. You can make your own named constant named for example

```
integer, parameter :: ìp = int64
```

But more importantly,

`(/3002, 3340403,....,19460630000/)`

is a default integer array expression there is no information available to make it kind 8. What is before the `=` assignment is irrelevant. An expression does not care about its context. Se also [Is There a Better Double-Precision Assignment in Fortran 90?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146005/is-there-a-better-double-precision-assignment-in-fortran-90)

You must indicate the kind

`(/3002_8, 3340403_8,....,19460630000_8/)`

or better

`(/3002_int64, 3340403_int64,....,19460630000_int64/)`

(or `_ip`)

Fortran 2003 also allows to define the type of an array constructor

```
 [ integer(int64) :: ]
```

but that will not help here, each individual constant in the expression must be legal.

Comment: @Vladimir: What about `(/3002.d0, 3340403.d0,....,19460630000.d0/)` ? Is this equivalent/portable ?

Comment: @Ian : Sorry, I mean if the array is real. If I use `integer, parameter :: real64 = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,307)` as precision kind, is it equivalent to write `3002.d0` and `3002_real64` ?

Comment: @Coriolis It would be equivalent provided the compiler is configured to have 64-bit double precision. Likely, but not guaranteed. Even if it is the default it can be set otherwise by compiler flags.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to specifying the KIND for each value in the array (as shown by @Vladimir), you may be able to use a compiler option so that by default any integers with unspecified KIND will be 8 bytes long.

For example, with Intel Fortran on Windows it is: `/integer-size:64`, or Linux: `-integer-size 64`.

I haven't tried it, but there seems to be a similar option in gfortran: `-fdefault-integer-8`