# How to solve "Error: Two main PROGRAMs at (1) and (2)"?

Tags: fortran

I am learning Fortran and encountered a problem with a program I am writing.

The program is below:

```
PROGRAM sco2
   IMPLICIT NONE
   REAL(8) :: verif, solub, T
   WRITE (*,*) "ENTER A TEMPERATURE"
   READ (*,*) verif
   WRITE (*,*) solub(verif)
END PROGRAM sco2

REAL(8) FUNCTION :: solub(T)
   IMPLICIT NONE
   REAL(8) :: A1, A2, A3
   A1 = -60.2409
   A2 = 93.4517
   A3 = 23.3585
   solub = exp(A1 + A2 * (100/T) + A3 * log(T/100))
END FUNCTION solub
```

When I tried to compile the program, I got the following error:

```
PROGRAM sco2
           1

IMPLICIT NONE
            2
Error: Two main PROGRAMs at (1) and (2)
```

And another one:

```
REAL(8) FUNCTION :: solub(T)
                  1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

I really don't know what to do and I'm really new to Fortran and coding in general, what did I do wrong ?

NB: I saw answers of already asked questions using "CONTAINS" but we didn't learn (how) to use it and are not supposed to, so I'm used to write functions without.

Comment: Learning to use `REAL(8)` is learning a bad habit. It is not good https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter Also, your literals like `-60.2409` are default `REAL` no matter if the variables you are assigning to are `REAL(8)`. This is a common source of errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146005/is-there-a-better-double-precision-assignment-in-fortran-90/42622204#42622204

Answer (score 0):

The function in your program is declared incorrectly. The error message

```
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

is quite exactly telling what is wrong. The `::` simply does not belong there.

After you fix that, you will find out that the argument `T` in undeclared, so you need to declare the type.

There is one `T` declared in the main program, but it is unrelated and it is unused.